# PHP memory limit detection

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

My questions is how I can detect real memory limit on hosting? The php.ini settings do not always represent the true limits, for example, memory_limit of 512MB, the script might fail at 128MB, same for max_execution time.

Comment: you can check it through the server command try this link : https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-commands-check-memory-usage#:~:text=Entering%20cat%20%2Fproc%2Fmeminfo%20in,memory%20used%20by%20the%20kernel.

Comment: thanks for the link, but the point is I need to detect it with php scrit to adjust resource usage

Answer (score 0):

If PHP exec commands are not blocked you could run a shell command like

```
$freeram_r = explode("\n", shell_exec("/usr/bin/free"));
```

and parse the result. Or directly for the parameter of your choice, e.g. get the real Gigabytes available from the /proc/meminfo output like

```
$available = shell_exec('awk \'/MemAvailable/ { printf "%.3f \n", $2/1024/1024 }\' /proc/meminfo');
```